# Check whether all textboxes are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm doing some simple validations using jQuery to check if all textboxes are filled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#<%= btnInsertCountry.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    var codeValue = $("#<%= txtCountryCode.ClientID %>").val();
    var nameValue = $("#<%= txtCountryName.ClientID %>").val();

    if (codeValue == "" || nameValue == "") {
        if (codeValue == "") {
            $("#divCodeValidation").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divCodeValidation").hide();
        }

        if (nameValue == "") {
            $("#divNameValidation").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#divNameValidation").hide();
        }

        return;
    }
});
});
```

The divs have the property `display: none` and contains the error message. This code works but I don't like it because I use an `if` to check if the values are empty and inside I have an `if` for each variable.

Is there a better way to do this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two validations are independent.  There's no point to `if (codeValue == "" || nameValue == "") { … }`.

---

Instead of calling `$.show()` and `$.hide()`, use [`$.toggle(display)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

> `display`
>   Type: Boolean
>   Use `true` to show the element or `false` to hide it.

---

You can also write [`$(function() { … })`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) instead of `$(document).ready(function() { … })`.

---

```
$(function () {    
    $("#<%= btnInsertCountry.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $("#divCodeValidation").toggle(
            "" == $("#<%= txtCountryCode.ClientID %>").val()
        );
        $("#divNameValidation").toggle(
            "" == $("#<%= txtCountryName.ClientID %>").val()
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your If statement is checking for `""` twice unnecessarily:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#<%= btnInsertCountry.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    var codeValue = $("#<%= txtCountryCode.ClientID %>").val();
    var nameValue = $("#<%= txtCountryName.ClientID %>").val();

 if (codeValue == "") {
        $("#divCodeValidation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divCodeValidation").hide();
    }

    if (nameValue == "") {
        $("#divNameValidation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#divNameValidation").hide();
    }

    return;

});
});
```